# How to iterate thru multiple arrays to form one to one mapping in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm reading the file below and splitting the values based on tab (values are tab separated) and assigning to 3 arrays.

**id_details.txt**

```
id\a_po87y  Jack    leader
id\ruio66   John_Marsha leader_1
id\rzd766   123_Smart_option    fresher
id\ruio66   John_Marsha automation_dev
....
etc
```

3 arrays

```
id = ["id\a_po87y", "id\ruio66", "id\rzd766", "id\ruio66", etc..]

store = ["Jack", "John_Marsha", "123_Smart_option", "John_Marsha", etc...]

group = ["leader", "leader_1", "fresher", "automation_dev", etc...]
```

**Jack_details.txt**

```
Joined on Feb 7, 2016
Created by: Solomon (ruio66) 

[groups]
leader_1 = id\rty67, id\mztrt, id\ruio66, ncr\025kc, id\a_po87y
automation = id\bzo0l4, ccr\poxz7j
automation_dev = id\ruio66
```

**John_Marsha_details.txt**

```
Joined on Jan 7, 2016
Created by: Jack Rondon 

[groups]
leader_1 = id\sop0r2, id\34_dev, id\mz4d5, id\ruio66
fresher = id\kzpo98, id\gz8sl7, id\cp0jxr, id\fzxlol, 
automation_dev = id\ruio66
```

Read the file - **Jack_details.txt** (1st value of store array) and go the row id - **leader** (1st value of group array) and delete the string - **id\a_po87y**(1st value id array) from that line only.

Similarly, check for string - id\ruio66 in the row id - leader_1 from the file - John_Marsha_details.txt and delete the string from that line.

Same has to be done for all the entries in the id_details.txt

its a direct one to one array mapping - "id -> store -> group" . With my beginner level experience I managed to write up the following code (incomplete) and I'm not sure how to achieve my requirement. Any suggestions to make it work ? Thanks in advance.

```
file_dir = 'E:/ruby_work'

file = File.open("E:/ruby_work/id_details.txt", "r")
contents = file.each_line.map { |line| line.split("\t") }.transpose
id, file_name, group  = contents


id.each do |ids|
  puts "For ID: #{ids}"
  file_name.each do |name| 
   value = File.open("#{file_dir}/#{name}_details.txt")
   text = File.read(value)
   #puts text
   text.each_line do |el|
    group.each do |gr|
     if el.match(/#{gr}/) then 
      print "group row #{gr}\n"
      print "Its matching\n"
      replace = text.gsub( /#{Regexp.escape(ids)}\,\s/, '').gsub( /#{Regexp.escape(ids)}/, '' ).gsub /,\s*$/, ''
      else print "Not\n"
         print "group row #{gr}\n"
     end
     group.shift
    end 
   end
   file_name.shift
  end

 end  
id.shift
```

Output I got

```
For ID: id\a_po87y
Not
group row leader

Not
group row leader_1

For ID: id\ruio66
```

My apologies for the long post and I hope I have conveyed the requirements correctly.

Comment: Why are you reading it into three arrays in the first place?

Comment: @DaveNewton : Thanks for looking into it. I'm not so confident about hash or other options, as I;ve posted, I'm very new to ruby so with my limited experience I opted for arrays.